# Read superuser process output in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to run a shell command using superuser (su) periodically in the following way:

first I get the su process:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

then, periodically I run:

```
p.getOutputStream().write("some shell command".getBytes());
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) //Process output line
```

this problem is that the r.readLine() blocks and does not return never. only if I create a new  su process and add p.getOutputStream().close() before reading output the code succeeds.

is there a way to use a single su process for issuing shell commands?

Comment: Are you using a root device or emulator? I'm asking this because there are only a few devices that let you execute root commands

Comment: I'm using a rooted device. Executing each command seperately works fine but I get many su toasts, I want to run the commands from a single su process instance...

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I've just come across the same issue, and it seems like I've resolved it by checking `r.ready()` on the BufferedReader. If there are no more lines to be read from the process output, then `r.ready()` returns false. I don't know how reliable this will be across different versions of the OS, but it works on 2.3.

Edit: also, before starting to read the output, make sure to sleep for a bit (say, 200ms) so that all of the output from your command gets in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the process with ProcessBuilder
Try:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder()
    .command("su")
    .redirectErrorStream(true)
        .start();
BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
while (inputReader.ready() && (line = inputReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
```

If you are not interested in differentiating the out and err streams, use redirectErrorStream(true) to merge the two streams. This simplifies your reading code and makes it easier to avoid blocking the target process. [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream%28%29)